# Angular Translate PascalPrecht UrlLoader

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-translate, angular-i18n

Can anyone tell me what should i do in  WebAPI when i use angular-translate? Now i am using StringBuilder to return the format of my keys and values like ;

```
{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'}]");
 return JArray.Parse(sb.ToString());
}
```

Is it the best way for returning Json array ? Or is there another better way to return Json array in appropriate format ?

Comment: I think you should mention what language is that in your post. Is that ASP.NET Web API? I would use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to store your key value pairs and use a JSON serializer to transform the dictionary into a JSON formatted string.

Comment: Asp.net web api i am using. I will try dictionary and let you know.Thanks.